# Are the cards in these videos cards from a real TCG, or just props?

Tags: identify-this-game, identify-this-game-piece

The video game Inscryption has a few segments where [in-game videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWDRv69oDZ0) depicting a fictional Youtuber opening card packs of what are supposed to be fictional card games are played. In these videos, the front faces of a few cards are displayed, and I'm not certain, but based on the overall design of the cards, they seem to be very similar to Magic: the Gathering cards.

Are the cards used for filming these video segments actual cards for a real TCG such as Magic: the Gathering, or are they just props that were designed and printed off for the filming of these videos? If they are real cards, is it possible to identify what cards they are, based off of what can be seen of their artwork?

The person in the video opens packs from "Catch Monsters", and mentions the card named "Transcendog", "Birchkin", and "Bandog".

He then opens another pack called "Inscryption" and mentions cards named "Mantis God" and "Blue Mage".

Only one card is shown close up, but very little actual detail can be seen:

[image]

Comment: Good question, I'm going to edit some of the card names and a screenshot from the video into your question so there is a bit more to go on.

Comment: My guess, considering Inscryption is a video game where you build decks and play a card game to defeat your opponent, is that these are all created for the in-game video. But that's a guess, not an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fictional / just props.

The boosters have no barcodes anywhere, so they're definitely fake. The cards themselves also look fake: overly simplistic art and scant text.

The clincher is that Google cannot find any record of the one card shown in close up (whose art is the exception to the simplistic style shown on the others; probably because it was made for close-ups).

FWIW: There's enough detail over the series of frames that card text can be extracted. It is:

> SKELETON
>
> Creature - Undead
>
> Brittle:
> After attacking, Skeleton perishes.

(No attack/defense values show on card).

The handwritten coordinates are:

> 49.301911 N
> 123.14154 W

(although that last digit crosses the borderline of the card so is hard to read, it might be a 9 or a 7 instead of a 4)